# How to call a method by the order of parameters in OOP?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose I have four classes A, B, C and Container

and I have the following objects and How to achieve the following output by only adding code to the container class?

the first call by "con" object should correspond to the the first parameter.

Your answer will be greatly appreciated !

```
A  a = new A();    
B  b = new B();    
C  c = new C();

Container  con = new Container(a,b,c);

con.calling();
con.calling();
con.calling();
```

the expected output is :

```
calling from A
calling from B
calling from C
```

---

```
public class A {    
    public void callA() {
        System.out.println("calling from A");
    }
}

public class B {        
    public void callB() {
        System.out.println("calling from B");
    }
}

public class C {
    public void callC() {
        System.out.println("calling from C");
    }
}

public class Container {        

    public Container(A a, B b, C c) {

    }

    public void calling(){

    }    
}
```

Comment: this seems confusing. Why would you want this?

Comment: You mean you wanto to call A in 1,4,7 times.. B 2,5,8 .. like this? :.s

Comment: By executing this con.calling(); one time, we can achieve this.

Comment: It's possible but not what I would call a good idea.  I think you're confusing some other topic with this.  Better would be to make three `Container`s and put one object inside each.  Then `calling()` just calls the inside object.  (Edit: or possibly what Prasath said.)

Comment: Have A, B and C implement some common interface. Have Container take instances of that interface, and put them into a Deque. Then in `calling()`, poll from that deque and call the method defined on that interface.

Comment: That's a really good question, as it involves practising of several techniques together.

Comment: Thank you all for the meaningful discussion on this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks very similar to `Iterator` pattern/interface. Here instead of `calling()` method it will be `next()`.

I can sketch it for you, something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Container implements Iterator {

    private Iterator<?> iter;

    public Container(Object ...values) {
        this.iter = Arrays.asList(values).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iter.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        return iter.next();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE** After some scrutiny consideration on you question, I've decided to expand my answer. Generally decision above with `Iterator` will give you only rough idea. You probably want more specific decision, and here it is with `java-8` method references:

1) Container with `Runnable` instances:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Container implements Iterator {

    private Iterator<Runnable> iter;

    public Container(Runnable ...values) {
        this.iter = Arrays.asList(values).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iter.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        Runnable next = iter.next();
        next.run();
        return next;
    }
}
```

And sample code to test this stuff:

```
Container container = new Container(new A()::callA, new B()::callB, new C()::callC);

container.next();
container.next();
container.next();
```

In this case it will not only return you next instance, but also invoke the desired method.

Comment: Iterating over a list is also a good idea.  The OP's idea, not so much.

Comment: You should use a non-raw Iterator: `Iterator<?>` or such.

Comment: Why I *should*, could you explain?

Comment: Because raw types are bad. The compiler warns you against doing this

Comment: "Don't use raw types in new code" is a general rule in Java.  C.f. Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java.*

Comment: @markspace until you are dealing with `Object` class.

Comment: Use `<?>` for Object.

Comment: In this _specific_ case, you're right, it's not different. But using raw types is a bad habit to get into, and in this specific case, the fix is also trivial -- add three characters, `<?>`. So why _wouldn't_ you, especially in the context of trying to teach someone good Java?

Comment: Ok :) Especially for you guys, here it is, I've added

Comment: More specifically user wants to invoke different methods from passed objects. I've updated my answer with alternative/expanded solution.

Comment: Thank you all for the meaningful discussion on this question.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a variable to take into account which time is the calling method executed, this could be the Container class:

```
class Container {

    int times = 0;

    A objectA;
    B objectB;
    C objectC;


    public Container(A a, B b, C c) {
        this.objectA = a;
        this.objectB = b;
        this.objectC = c;
    }

    public void Calling(){
        if(this.times==0){
            a.callA();
        }
        if(this.times==1){
            b.callB();
        }
        if(this.times==2){
            c.callC();
        }
        this.times++;
    }
}
```